# 3D Print Toolbox Volume report with wrong number

Tags: add-on

I have read the 3D Print Toolbox documentation from the Blender site, also searched in Google and Blender Stack Exchange and did not found any case like this.

I have modeled a concrete structure. I use the 3D Print Toolbox to calculate de volume of every structural element.

When pressing the Volume key of elements that are prisms the volume is correct, but when I press Volume of the stairs the reported volume is wrong, is bigger than the correct value.

I duplicate several times the stairs object to be repeated in each flor. Each duplicate stair object reports a volume that is greater than the previous flor.

You can see a video of the screen capture here: https://youtu.be/jls-KH8Rnz4

Is this a bug?

Greetings from Paraguay.

Claudio Bogado Pompa.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: The 3D print tool box volume requires manifold geometry. If the Solid (Solidez) check fails, you will see changes in volume with changes in position as in your question.